# Microsoft Graph rights for admin

Tags: graph, azure-active-directory

Global admin account, can't access device configuration information... can someone eli5 this to me?

I run this in Graph Explorer:

```
GET /deviceManagement/deviceConfigurations/e0a39e0c-98ce-427a-b10f-31f49b8736e1/deviceStatusOverview
```

And I get this:

[image: result]

This is the rights of the logged in account:

[image: account role AAD]

Comment: Please provide permissions DeviceManagementConfiguration.ReadWrite.All, DeviceManagementConfiguration.Read.All

Answer (score 0):

One has to explicitly consent to each dataset you want graph to access.